# What are eligible service providers for SAQ-D in PCI DSS?

Tags: pci-dss

PCI SSC specifies that Self-Assessment Questionnaire D can be used by "eligible" service providers ([source](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/completing_self_assessment)):

> **Questionnaire D**. For Service Providers: All service providers defined by a payment card brand as eligible to complete a Self-Assessment Questionnaire.

How can one identify whether service provider is SAQ-D eligible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Level 2 Service Providers are eligible to use the Self-Assessment Questionnaire.  As [PCI Policy Portal](https://pcipolicyportal.com/what-is-pci/service-providers/) summarizes, these are defined as:

> - [Level 2] Service Provider Criteria for [VISA](https://usa.visa.com/dam/VCOM/download/merchants/data-security-compliane-service-providers.pdf): Any service provider that stores, processes and/or transmits less than 300,000 Visa
>     transactions annually.
> - [Level 2] Service Provider Criteria for [MasterCard](https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/merchants/safety-security/security-recommendations/service-providers-need-to-know.html): (1). Includes all DSE’s that store, transmit, or process less than 300,000 total
>     combined MasterCard and Maestro transactions annually.

Additionally, [American Express](https://www.americanexpress.com/content/dam/amex/common/merchant/datasecurity/data-security/DSOP%20Merchant%20US%20Oct%2018.pdf) defines Level 2 Service Providers as "less than 2.5 million American Express Card Transactions per year; or any Service Provider not deemed Level 1 by American Express."

In practice, you will rarely see a Service Provider - even a Level 2 - using an SAQ. They don't get a heck of a lot of respect out of QSAs, and QSAs are the ones deciding how hard to look at a given merchants' chosen Service Providers.

Answer (score 0):

Page 17 of the SAQ guidelines (https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ-InstrGuidelines-v3_2.pdf) defines service provider as eligible if:

"SAQ D for Service Providers applies to all service providers defined by a payment brand as being
SAQ-eligible."

This document also provides a helpful visual guide to choosing the correct SAQ on page 18.

https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/glossary#S Defines service provider as:
"Business entity that is not a payment brand, directly involved in the processing, storage, or transmission of cardholder data on behalf of another entity. This also includes companies that provide services that control or could impact the security of cardholder data. Examples include managed service providers that provide managed firewalls, IDS and other services as well as hosting providers and other entities. If an entity provides a service that involves only the provision of public network access—such as a telecommunications company providing just the communication link—the entity would not be considered a service provider for that service (although they may be considered a service provider for other services)."

Edit* edited to reflect definition for service providers.  Also the visual guide applies to service providers and merchants.

Comment: Thanks, @DarkMatter. I see that you pointed out to SAQ-D eligibility criteria for **merchants**. However, I am interested in eligibility criteria for **service providers**.

Comment: thanks. You wrote "_applies to all service providers defined by a payment brand as being SAQ-eligible_". Where do payment brands define what service providers are SAQ-eligible?

Comment: thanks. I believe you provided a definition of service provider in general. I am looking to understand what makes service provider **SAQ-eligible**. Because SAQ-D can be used only by SAQ-eligible service providers, and not by all service providers.

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: @sirdarpeace What sort of business is it? What sort of data do you process?  what sort of data do you store?

Comment: @sirdarpeace furthermore if you are a PCI compliant provider you hopefully should already be on payment brand registries such as https://www.visa.com/splisting/searchGrsp.do

Comment: Credit card information and cardholder data. And I am looking for a documentation to identify whether this scenario is SAQ-D eligible or not. Could you please point to specific documentation if you know one?

Comment: @sirdarpeace In that case my assumption is (as long as you are not actually a merchant in any way) then you are a service provider...but don't believe me...go to the source...contact a payment brand...visa is a good choice.  https://mssip.visa.com/ <--- form for getting officially recognized as a PCI-compliant servicer